# Map of Map, how to update key of inner Map Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to update key in inner Map which is value of top level Map, for this 
I have given 3 code snippets here first  2 are working and trying to understand why 3rd one is not working.

This is structure of mapOfMap variable, key value classed can be replaced with real classes.

```
Map<TopLevelMapKey, Map<InnerMapKey, InnerMapValue>> mapOfMap;
```

This is First version works fine.

```
mapOfMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .forEach(topMap -> map
      .put(topMap.getKey(),
         topMap.getValue()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                         innerMapEntry -> innerMapEntry.getKey().getUpdatedKey, Map.innerMapEntry::getValue,
                        (v1, v2) -> {
                          throw new RuntimeException(" Exception in merging, duplicates not allowed.");},
                         TreeMap::new))));
```

This is second version, probably best approach here, also works fine.

```
mapOfMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                              topMap -> topMap.getValue()
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap( innerMapEntry -> innerMapEntry.getKey().getUpdatedKey,
                                                        Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                        v1, v2) -> {
                                                        throw new RuntimeException(" Exception in merging, duplicates not allowed.");}, 
                                                        TreeMap::new ))
        ));
```

This one is not working, it returns empty Map, not able to understand why.
In this I am calling collect over top level Map and collecting result in supplier HashMap::new, in accumulator I am calling one more collect over inner map which I am collecting in TreeMap, now I expect accumulator output to be combined in top level Map using HashMap::putAll combiner provided there.

```
mapOfMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new,
             (hashMap, topMap) ->
                 topMap.getValue()
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .collect( TreeMap::new,
                              (treeMap, innerMap) ->  treeMap.put(innerMap.getKey().getUpdatedKey, innerMap.getValue()),
                               TreeMap::putAll),
             HashMap::putAll);
```

Comment: what is `throwingMerger`, what is your resultant data structure? and you are anyway ignoring the result of inner `collect` (stream) operation with your last approach. Your current operation looks as simple as iterating on the elements of the maps using `Map.forEach` as `mapOfMap.forEach((ok, ov) -> ov.forEach((ik, iv) -> {
            ov.merge(ik.getUpdatedKey(), iv, (val1, val2) -> {
                throw new AlcyoneRuntimeException("Exception in merging, duplicates not allowed.");
            });
        }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of your inner `collect()`. You should put that in the given `hashMap` value:

```
mapOfMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new,
                (hashMap, topMap) -> {
                    TreeMap<TopLevelMapKey, InnerMapValue> value = topMap.getValue()
                            .entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(TreeMap::new,
                                    (treeMap, innerMap) -> treeMap.put(innerMap.getKey().getUpdatedKey(), innerMap.getValue()),
                                    TreeMap::putAll);
                    hashMap.put(topMap.getKey(), value);
                },
                HashMap::putAll);
```